# c# usercontrol transparency

Tags: c#, user-controls, transparency

it's possible to have a usercontrol over my form and set a transparency percentage?
I Wish have the background of the usercontrol to 70% transparent, but the buttons and the rest of the components to 100%

it's possible?
thanks

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms? (edit: WPF yes)

Comment: @Gerrie Schenck - did you mean WPF? Anyways, there's still the possibility of ASP.NET webforms, WPF browser app and Silverlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to the control's constructor:

```
base.CreateParams.ExStyle |= 0x20;            
SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0x80,0xFF,0xCC,0x33);
```

Comment: Try this yourself before posting.

Comment: this works, but make the form completely transparent but not over the buttons etc...

Comment: Sorry, I just typed it in the box, should've checked. Fixed the post now so it compiles.

Comment: If you're looking for true transparency with winforms and GDI+ sooner or later you'll be disappointed. I spent some time trying things but ultimately gave up. I ended up calling all I need in OnPaint of the parent control. It gives the desired effect but, of course, ruins the flexibility and all other advantages that user controls give.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting a one by one pixel png with the desired transparency (alpha channel) as the background for your button. This should work with WinForms, WPF and webforms.

Answer (score 2):

On WPF you can use Opacity property like this

```
<!-- XAML -->

<!-- 50% Transparency -->
<Label Opacity="0.5"/>

<!-- 80% Transparency -->
<Label Opacity="0.2"/>
```